# Error with getch()

Tags: c++, arrays, getch

```
void move_player(int& x, int& y) {
int old_x, old_y, new_x, new_y;
switch (getch()) {
case 0x31: // miscare stanga
    if (current_x>min_x) {
        old_x=x;
        new_x=x-1;
        if (y==1) {
            path[1][old_x]=' ';
            path[1][new_x]=player;
            system("cls");
            for (int y=0;y<3;y++) {
                for (int x=0;x<20;x++) {
                    cout << path[y][x];
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        } else if (y==2) {
            path[2][old_x]='_';
            path[2][new_x]=player;
            system("cls");
            for (int y1=0;y1<3;y1++) {
                for (int x1=0;x1<20;x1++) {
                    cout << path[y1][x1];
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
break;
case 0x32:
    if (x<max_x) {
        old_x=current_x;
        new_x=current_x+1;
        if (y==1) {
            path[1][old_x]=' ';
            path[1][new_x]=player;
            system("cls");
            for (int y2=0;y2<3;y2++) {
                for (int x2=0;x2<20;x2++) {
                    cout << path[y2][x2];
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        } else if (y==2) {
            path[2][old_x]='_';
            path[2][new_x]=player;
            system("cls");
            for (int y3=0;y3<3;y3++) {
                for (int x3=0;x3<20;x3++) {
                    cout << path[y3][x3];
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
break;
case 0x33:
    if (y>min_y) {
        old_y=y;
        new_y=y-1;
        path[old_y][x]='_';
        path[new_y][x]=player;
        system("cls");
        for (int y4=0;y4<3;y4++) {
            for (int x4=0;x4<20;x4++) {
                cout << path[y4][x4];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
break;
case 0x34:
    if (y<max_y) {
        old_y=y;
        new_y=y+1;
        path[old_y][x]=' ';
        path[new_y][x]=player;
        system("cls");
        for (int y5=0;y5<3;y5++) {
            for (int x5=0;x5<20;x5++) {
                cout << path[y5][x5];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
x=new_x;
y=new_y;
```

}

This is the function for moving a player in a two dimensional space.
It is represented by an array which I declared as `char path[3][20]` and the player can only move in `path[1][20]` or `path[2][20]`. The first layer of the array is just represented by a bunch of lines, kind of setting the boundaries for the map. Btw, the player starts at `path[2][0]` or lower left corner.
(I can't move it left or down in the starting position, only right or up)

The problem is, that when I run this, I can move it fine just once right, but then when I try it to move left or right it does nothing, and when I try to move it up or down the console just frezees and it quits.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Where is `current_x` declared - moving left depends on the current value of `current_x`, but nothing changes it inside the code you have shown.

Comment: can you please narrow down the problem to small piece of code.. it will help you even in analyzing..

Comment: Also note that if you type something that is not '1', '2', '3', '4', (such as a carriage return to make the input work), your code will set `x` to `new_x` which has not been initialized. Even when you press '1', `new_y` is used without having a value assigned to it.

Comment: current_x is a global int. I forgot to change it

Comment: I've also set x to 0 and y to 2 but I'm not sure what to write in the default for the switch func

Comment: @JossieCalderon x31 was an experimental aircraft used to test new (well new for the early 1990's) ideas in flight control and thrust vectoring.